# Handle click for recycle view parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycle view horizontaly which sometimes contains one or two elements and may not cover entire screen.

I want to handle click for the rest of empty space on right but since by default recycler view is match parent the click listener on container does not work.

Is it possible to stop recycler taking click entirely and its parent container (say Linear Layout) handle click

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_friend_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/ad_detail_friend_recycle_min_height" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried making recycler element as disabled and even whole recycler list clickable and focusable false.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem lies with the fact that you are not able to set property wrap_content to the width of the recycler view(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772)

However there is a workaround for the same available [here](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java) which is to set a custom layout manager which shall enable you to set the wrap_content property to the recycler-view. Now set a click listener on the linear-layout and you are good to go.

Now, there is another way which i'm not sure will work, but what if you set a onclicklistener on the recycler-view itself??;-)

Comment: I tried adding onclick to recycler view itself ,didn't work for me though.

Comment: I think the example does not work for horizontal orientation ? It did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the new support library 23.2.0 this issue is fixed now.

Comment: How did you figure it out?